# How to initialize nolimits4web:swiper in meteor helper

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, swiper.js

I managed to get the swiper working by having the following in my onRendered function:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
// Optional parameters
direction: 'vertical',
loop: false,
scrollbarSnapOnRelease: true,
watchSlidesProgress: true,
pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
paginationHide: false
//further parameters at http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WPMOXt8xA8o
});
$('.block-btn').focus(function() {
$('.block-btn .cls-1').css({"fill": "#3A3A3A"});
});
$('.block-btn').blur(function() {
$('.block-btn .cls-1').css({"fill": "#e2e2e2"});
});
```

Now I want to have a card deck (e.g. tinder) and the slider is within each card. With the onRendered function the slider is only initialized on the first cards. On the following cards it does not work. How can I initialize it everytime something changes (a new profile card is being shown)? A simple helper did not work

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after posting this, I found that using mySwiper.update() in a seperate helper fixed it. For some reason the bullets do not reset thought. I just leave this here in case somebody takes as long as me to find the answer ;)

http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WPMZUt8xA8o